# How can I embed a smartphone simulator in html5?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to embed a smartphone in my website and display webpages in its screen. Everything would be in html(I prefer 5), css and js and I dont know if there is any plugin that does this because I have no idea how to do it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the simple thing you want to do is take a photo of your phone then overlay a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Insert an image of a phone on the page, with the correct dimensions so the screen is big enough on the phone.
- Make a div with the screens dimensions and position it on top of the phone image.
- Insert an iframe in the div with both width and height set to 100%.
- Use a predetermined URL in the iframe, or set one dynamically with JS.